# Angularjs & Karma controller unit test injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, controller, karma-runner

In order to apply some unit test to my AngularJS controller, I'm unable to get it working correctly...

This is my Angularjs app declaration :

```
    var ogcApp = angular.module('OGC', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'xeditable',
    'ngRoute',
    'ogc.services',
    'ogc.controllers',
    'restangular',
    'AngularStomp',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ogc.directives',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'jlareau.pnotify',
    'ngTagsInput'
]);
```

Here is my controller prototype :

```
angular.module('ogc.controllers').controller('applicantController', function ($scope, $log, $location, $cacheFactory, ngstomp, identityService, Restangular) { ...Some code... }
```

Here is my karma.conf.js :

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/AngularStompDK/dist/angular-stomp.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/pnotify/pnotify.core.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/main/webapp/static/js/*.js',
        'src/test/karma/**/*.spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And this is my simple test :

```
    describe('UNIT : applicantController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('OGC'));

    var ctrl, scope, aSearchForm;
    // inject the $controller and $rootScope services
    // in the beforeEach block
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        // Create the controller
        ctrl = $controller('ogc.controllers.applicantController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should instantiate the controller properly', function () {
        expect(ctrl).not.toBeUndefined();
    });
})
```

And I got this error on karma server logs :

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 UNIT : applicantController should instantiate the controller properly FAILED
       Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module restangular due to:
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _
```

And a simple :

```
 expect(true).toBe(true);
```

Doesn't work while the beforeEach with the injection is there, so I think the problems is on the dependencies injection but where ?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this code:

```
ctrl = $controller('ogc.controllers.applicantController', {
  $scope: scope
});
```

to just this:

```
ctrl = $controller('applicantController', {
  $scope: scope
});
```

There is no real namespace concept in angularjs yet. All the things from different modules will be mixed into the same bucket.

PS. As a general tip, try using an unminified `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` while debugging, it would give you a more meaningful error.

**EDIT:** It turned out that there is also an another problem:

Either the `lodash` or `underscore` library is missing, it is required by `Restangular`.

Comment: I already test with this controller declaration, now with the angular.js on Karma conf file I got this error : "Error [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module restangular due to: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _"

Comment: You might forgot to include `lodash/underscore` library in `karma.config.js`, it is required by restangular.

Comment: runTarm, thank you ! I forgot _ and lodash links.. now I have other depandencies issues that I have to solve..

Comment: Thanks for the general tip to use non-minified angular.js!